# Testing destroy methods with capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, destroy

I've written some tests using Capybara, but I'm not using selenium and neither any other JS drivers. But my doubt is if I can test a destroy method this way? Since I need to confirm a JS confirmation and the data-method = "delete" can't be visited...

I would like to do something very Capybara's way like:

visit '/people/123', :data-method => 'delete'

Do you guys know if is there some way to do that?

Thanks in advance,
Andre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has JavaScript code which generates a form from the link's `href` and `data-method` attributes and submits it; this won't work without JS.

One way to test this: first, test for the presence of the link and proper attributes (`href`, `data-method`), then trigger the delete request manually with the [`Capybara::RackTest::Driver#delete` method](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb#L75). If you do this often, write a helper method wrapping those two steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Besides that I found a blog post about the same problem (http://blog.ardes.com/2010/4/28/capybara-and-rack-test-sessions-and-http-methods) and he managed to solve it with the lines: rack_test_session_wrapper = Capybara.current_session.driver
  rack_test_session_wrapper.process :delete,mycontrollerpath(@item)

Answer (score 4):

Just something to be aware of with @Mike Mazur's answer, if your controller does a redirect on the `#destroy` action, invoking the delete method on Capybara's driver doesn't actually follow the redirect.  Instead it just populates the `response` with the redirection message, i.e. `body == <html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://www.example.com/model_names\">redirected</a>.</body></html>` and `status_code == 302`.

So, to get everything populated like you would expect on a normal Capybara `click_button 'Delete Model'`, you'll need to manually follow the redirect.  One (unrefactored and RSpec flavored) way to do this:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.delete controller_path(model_instance)
Capybara.current_session.driver.response.should be_redirect
visit Capybara.current_session.driver.response.location
```

Comment: wow this is perfect. Thanks. Any reason you are specifying Capybara.current_session vs just using page?